# How to implement state and country picklist on customer portal

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

Currently i am using MailingCountry(Standard Contact field under mailing address) on my VF page in customer portal but it is rendering as input field instead of picklist, as i have enabled State and Country Picklist feature in my org. What's the reason for that? In native salesforce environment it is working correctly but in customer portal it's not working.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!LOWER(f.fieldPath) == 'mailingcountry'}">
       <apex:outputLabel value="Country" />

       <apex:inputField label="Country" styleClass="country"
       style="width:150px;" value="{!student.mailingCountry}" 
       required="{!OR(f.required,f.dbrequired)}" />                                                                     
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

This is the code for VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
 <apex:form>
  <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It is also not showing up in simple VF page in salesforce Envronment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using value="{!contact.MailingCountryCode}" in your apex:inputField.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing code i'm kind of firing in the dark here, but i'm going to guess that you've included the field on your vf page as an Apex:inputText field, rather than an Apex:InputField Field?

Comment: Plz check out the code i have added!!

Comment: just read over here: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US that State and country picklists don't work with partner portals. While I realize that Partner Portals and Customer Portals are different, they are similar enough that I suspect you may be hitting a limitation of the feature.

Comment: It is also not working on VF page in salesforce environment. Please check the code i have added.